# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I'm new to Flutter. I am trying to develop an application.

I want to show the staff list in the Firebase database. However, I am getting the following error.

**Error :**

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver
> can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding
> a null check to the target ('!').

Kodlarım :

```
`import 'package:calendar/page/mainPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Staff extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StaffState createState() => _StaffState();
}

class _StaffState extends State<Staff> {
  
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    CollectionReference staffRef = _firestore.collection('staff');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Personel Listesi"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent[400],
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MainPage()),
                  (route) => true);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: staffRef.snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot) {
                    if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(
                          child: Text(
                              "Bir hata oluştu, lütfen tekrar deneyiniz."));
                    } else {
                      if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> listStaff =
                            asyncSnapshot.data.docs;
                        return Flexible(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Card(
                                  elevation: 20,
                                  color: Colors.greenAccent[200],
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    trailing: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        await listStaff[index]
                                            .reference
                                            .delete();
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    title: Text(
                                      '${listStaff[index].data['nameSurname']}',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                    ),
                                    subtitle: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              '${listStaff[index].data['tip']}',
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              '${listStaff[index].data['mail']}',
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              '${listStaff[index].data['phone']}',
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              itemCount: listStaff.length),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
`
```

Answer (score 20):

In the new flutter update, we don't need to add `.data()`

my codes below

```
title: Text(
                                  **'${listStaff[index].data['nameSurname']}',**
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                ),
```

**Changing it like this fixed the error.**

```
title: Text(
                                  **'${listPersonel[index]['nameSurname']}'**,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                ),
```

Comment: May the solution be using `.get()` instead of `.data()` ?

Answer (score 17):

#### Problem:

You get this error if you're accessing an element on a nullable `List` or `Map`. Let's understand it for a `List` and you can apply the same solutions for your `Map`.

For example:

```dart
List<int>? someList;

void main() {
  int a = someList[0]; // Error
}
```

---

#### Solutions:

- Use a **local variable**:

  ```dart
  var list = someList;
  if (list != null) {
    int a = list[0]; // No error
  }
  ```
- Use **`?`** and **`??`**:

  ```dart
  int a = someList?[0] ?? -1; // -1 is the default value if List was null
  ```
- Use **`!`** bang operator only if you're sure that the `List` isn't `null`.

  ```dart
  int a = someList![0];
  ```

---

#### For those who are using `FutureBuilder`/`StreamBuilder`:

You can solve the error in two ways:

- Specify a type to your `FutureBuilder`/`StreamBuilder`

  ```dart
  FutureBuilder<List<int>>( // <-- type 'List<int>' is specified.
    future: _listOfInt(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<int> myList = snapshot.data!; // <-- Your data
      }
      return Container();
    },
  )
  ```
- Use `as` to downcast `Object` to your type, say a `List` or `Map`.

  ```dart
  FutureBuilder(
    future: _listOfInt(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        var myList = snapshot.data! as List<int>; // <-- Your data using 'as'
      }
      return Container();
    },
  )
  ```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem as the questioner and the solution came from this post. I leave it here in case anyone else has this problem.
https://fileidea.com/2021/05/05/method-cant-be-unconditionally-invoked-because-the-receiver-can-be-null-with-firestore/

before:

```
 final mySnapStream = messagesCollection
.orderBy('date', descending: true)
.limit(100)
.snapshots()
.map((obj) => obj.docs
    .map((e) => new MyItem(
        e.data()['myFieldOne'],
        e.data()['myFieldThree'],
        e.data()['myFieldFour']))
    .toList());

after:

    final mySnapStream = messagesCollection
  .orderBy('date', descending: true)
  .limit(100)
  .snapshots()
  .map((obj) => obj.docs
      .map((e) => new MyItem(
          (e.data() as dynamic)['myFieldOne'],
          (e.data() as dynamic)['myFieldThree'],
          (e.data() as dynamic)['myFieldFour']))
      .toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a typical null-safety related error. I did not try the code, by I guess that probably assigning  `asyncSnapshot.data.docs` to `listStaff` possibly may return **null**, but your declared type `List<DocumentSnapshot>` doesn't allow for that. If you are 100% sure that this assignment won't return null value, you can add '!' to ensure compiler, that it will be List, so it will let you use methods. Although if you want this list to be nullabe, you can simply add '?' to show it, and than use '?.' to use methods. It works like: Check if the object is null and execute method on this method only if its not.