# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null' | Firebase Database | Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

I'am getting the error  `The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').` Below is my code

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class Users {
  String? id;
  String? email;
  String? name;
  String? phone;
  Users({
    this.id,
    this.email,
    this.name,
    this.phone,
  });

  Users.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    id = dataSnapshot.key!;
    email = dataSnapshot.value['email'];
    name = dataSnapshot.value['name'];
    phone = dataSnapshot.value['phone'];
  }
}
```

The Error is in the last 3 lines

```
email = dataSnapshot.value['email'];
name = dataSnapshot.value['name'];
phone = dataSnapshot.value['phone'];
```

I have already added null safety operators. But it still shows an error.

Comment: Can you check here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575893/the-method-cant-be-unconditionally-invoked-because-the-receiver-can-be-nu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The method '\[\]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575893/the-method-cant-be-unconditionally-invoked-because-the-receiver-can-be-nu)

Comment: add `!` before `['email']` so `dataSnapshot.value!['email'];` but be sure that it will never be `null`

Answer (score 0):

A `DataSnapshot` object does not necessarily have a value, so its `value` property may be null. You need to check whether the snapshot has a value, before trying to read properties from it:

```
Users.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  id = dataSnapshot.key!;
  if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
    email = dataSnapshot.value!['email'];
    name = dataSnapshot.value!['name'];
    phone = dataSnapshot.value!['phone'];
 }
}
```

Note the added `if` statements, and the `!` marks that Pokaboom also commented about.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
 Users.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    List<User> userData = dataSnapshot.value!.toList();
    id = dataSnapshot.key!;
    email = userData['email'];
    name = userData['name'];
    phone = userData['phone'];
  }
```

maybe this work