# The method 'add' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Using for in loop to get a list of data. Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, for-loop, addition

I'm new to programming and I'm learning flutter.
I'm trying to loop through a list of _tasks to get the tasks that has the parentId I need.

- Error: The method 'add' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
- Question 1: I already make sure the item is not null in the **if** statement, but the **add** method still think the **item** could be null.. How do I prevent this?
- Question 2: If there a better way to get a list of *Tasks* without using **for in** loop?

```
class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Task> _tasks = [
  Task(parentId: 1, name: "Task1"),
  Task(parentId: 1, name: "Task2"),
  Task(parentId: 2, name: "Task3"),
  Task(parentId: 3, name: "Task3"),
  ];

  List<Task>? getTasksByParentId(int parentId) {
    List<Task>? TasksWithSameListId;

    if (_tasks.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var item in _tasks) {
        if (item.parentId == parentId) {
          TasksWithSameListId.add(item);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Expecting result: when calling function **getTasksByParentId**, it should return a list of Tasks that has the same parentId.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The method '\[\]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575893/the-method-cant-be-unconditionally-invoked-because-the-receiver-can-be-nu)

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because your variable `TasksWithSameListId` is `nullable`. Also never initialized. To fix your issue you can initialize it and make it non nullable.

```
List<Task> getTasksByParentId(int parentId) {
  final List<Task> tasksWithSameId = [];

  if (_tasks.isNotEmpty) {
    for (var item in _tasks) {
      if (item.parentId == parentId) {
        tasksWithSameId.add(item);
      }
    }
  }
  return tasksWithSameId;
}
```

A better approach is to use [where](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) to filter your list.

```
List<Task> getTasksByParentId(int parentId) {
  return _tasks.where((item) => item.parentId == parentId).toList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue :D