# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. how to put conditions in this code

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class Post {
  static const KEY = "key";
  static const DATE = "date";
  static const TITLE = "title";
  static const BODY = "body";
  final String date;
  String key;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  Post(this.date, this.key, this.title, this.body);

  // String get ket => _key;
  //
  // String get date => _date;
  //
  // String get title => _title;
  //
  // String get body => _body;

  Post.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snap)
      : key = snap.key.toString(),
        body = snap.value[BODY],
        date = snap.value[DATE],
        title = snap.value[TITLE];

  toMap() {
    return {BODY: body, TITLE: title, DATE: date};
  }
}
```

error:

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. (unchecked_use_of_nullable_value at [flutter_firebase] lib\models\post.dart:25)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the code + error message, but also a textual description on what the code is supposed to do, and what it currently does, see [mcve]. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The method '\[\]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575893/the-method-cant-be-unconditionally-invoked-because-the-receiver-can-be-nu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` in `snap.value` can be `null` on line 25. And then, trying to use [the index operator](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/List/operator_get.html) `[]` on it (a possible `null` value) shows this error (It'd be the same as doing `null[]`).

### Solution 1

Try checking where the data come from if it can be `null`. If that's the case, i.e. if `null` is really possible from `DataSnapshot`, you'd need to specify `Post` properties with a [nullable type](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator) as well with the `?` after the type like so:

```dart
class Post {
  static const KEY = "key";
  static const DATE = "date";
  static const TITLE = "title";
  static const BODY = "body";
  final String? date;
  String key;
  final String? title;
  final String? body;

  Post(this.date, this.key, this.title, this.body);

  ...
```

And then default the value to something else using the `?` [unary postfix operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators) in conjunction with `??` [if-null operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions) if it comes as `null` like the code snippet below. You'd need also to cast the `snap.value`, that is a `Object?` in the new Firestore 9.x, to a nullable `Map<String, dynamic>?`.

```dart
  Post.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snap)
      : key = snap.key.toString(),
        body = (snap.value as Map<String, dynamic>?)?[BODY] ?? '',
        date = (snap.value as Map<String, dynamic>?)?[DATE] ?? '',
        title = (snap.value as Map<String, dynamic>?)?[TITLE] ?? '';
```

### Solution 2

Otherwise, if `null` is not a possibility at all then you can force the value to be non-null with the `!` [null assertion operator](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator), casting away nullability, like so:

```dart
  Post.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snap)
      : key = snap.key.toString(),
        body = (snap.value! as Map<String, dynamic>)[BODY],
        date = (snap.value! as Map<String, dynamic>)[DATE],
        title = (snap.value! as Map<String, dynamic>)[TITLE];
```

Comment: I've edited my anwser with an amendment to solution 1. Please check

Comment: hii @lepsch
i tried both of the solution
but it give me the error
"error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (undefined_operator at [flutter_firebase] lib\models\post.dart:25)"

Comment: Most probably you're gonna need to cast `snap.value` to a `Map` like: `(snap.value! as Map<String, dynamic>)[BODY]` and so on. Please try it so I can update the answer