# The argument type 'List<Contact>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<MultiSelectItem<dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, list, multi-select

I am trying to test flutter_contacts library.
I am willing to build a view where the user can select several contacts and display each of them in a chip when selected. My problem is that I have List Contact. But for the multiselect, I must provide a List<MultiSelectItem>.
Please, do you know if I can convert my List Contact into List<MultiSelectItem>.

Many thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/bottom_sheet/multi_select_bottom_sheet_field.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/chip_display/multi_select_chip_display.dart';

void TEST() => runApp(const FlutterContactsExample());

final _multiSelectKeyContext = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();

class FlutterContactsExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlutterContactsExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
 State<FlutterContactsExample>  createState() => _FlutterContactsExampleState();

}

class _FlutterContactsExampleState extends State<FlutterContactsExample> {
  List<Contact>? _contacts;
  bool _permissionDenied = false;
  late List<bool> isChecked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchContacts();
  }

  Future _fetchContacts() async {
    if (!await FlutterContacts.requestPermission(readonly: true)) {
      setState(() => _permissionDenied = true);
    } else {
      final contacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts();
      setState(() => _contacts = contacts);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('flutter_contacts_example')),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              _body(),

              ///MultiSelect for Context
              MultiSelectBottomSheetField(
                key: _multiSelectKeyContext,
                initialChildSize: 0.7,
                maxChildSize: 0.95,
                title: const Text("Context", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),),
                buttonText: const Text(
                  "Context", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),),
                searchTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                searchHintStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                itemsTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                items: _contacts,
                searchable: true,
                onConfirm: (valueContext) {
                  setState(() {
                    _contextSelected = valueContext;
                    print('mon test ligne 152');
                    print(_contextSelected);
                  });
                  _multiSelectKeyContext.currentState!.validate();

                },
                chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 19),
                  onTap: (dynamic item) {
                    setState(() {
                    });
                    _multiSelectKeyContext.currentState!.validate();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 40),
            ],
          )));

  Widget _body() {
    if (_permissionDenied) return const Center(child: Text('Permission denied'));
    if (_contacts == null) return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _contacts!.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(
            title: (Text(_contacts![i].displayName)),
           
            onTap: () async {
              final fullContact =
              await FlutterContacts.getContact(_contacts![i].id);
              await Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ContactPage(fullContact!)));
            }
         )
    );
  }
}
```

```
class ContactPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Contact contact;
   const ContactPage(this.contact, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(contact.displayName)),
      body: Column(children: [
        Text('First name: ${contact.name.first}'),
        Text('Last name: ${contact.name.last}'),
        Text(
            'Phone number: ${contact.phones.isNotEmpty ? contact.phones.first.number : '(none)'}'),
        Text(
            'Email address: ${contact.emails.isNotEmpty ? contact.emails.first.address : '(none)'}'),
      ]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `MultiSelectBottomSheetField` instead of

```
items: _contacts,
```

you should write it like this:

```
items: _contacts.map((e) => MultiSelectItem(e, e.name)).toList(),
```

as shown here: [link to example](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter#usage:%7E:text=items%3A%20_animals.map((e)%20%3D%3E%20MultiSelectItem(e%2C%20e.name)).toList()%2C).

Because as the error you got and documentation both says, it needs `List<MultiSelectItem<V>>` [here](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter#usage:%7E:text=opening%20the%20dialog.-,items,The%20source%20list%20of%20options.,-itemsTextStyle) and you gave it `List<Contact>?`

Comment: thank you. I have tried. I am getting this error The method 'map' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. And this one The argument type 'Name' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: @LaurentThomas this answer explains very accurately what I want to write about `List<Contact>?` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68662355/12862313. So after understanding the answer use `!` or  `?` at your discreation. Also in my answer `e.name` was just an example since I don't know what data members are available.