# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. In Model

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I have this problem in my snapshot

The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B2FB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T439r.png)

[image]

[image]

Greetings I hope you are very well, someone could help me, it is my first time creating a mobile app and with firebare.

I tried by Var, put ! and nothing, I am not very aware of the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The method '\[\]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575893/the-method-cant-be-unconditionally-invoked-because-the-receiver-can-be-nu)

Comment: Try to include code as Plain text in the code. This will Helps SEO.

Comment: What did you get on console when  `print(snapshot.value);` runs ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var horario = snapshot.value == null ? "" : snapshot.value!['nombre'];
```

Comment: I get this error in the [] section                                                                                           
Type: String

The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'

Answer (score 0):

**I changed the version of the dependencies and the problem was solved.**

before

```
firebase_core: ^2.1.1
cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3
firebase_database: ^10.0.2
```

after

```
firebase_core: ^1.4.0
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.5
firebase_database: ^6.0.0
```