# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I couldn't retrieve the data from another screen from an item within a list view using flutter and firebase. I keep having this error even if add a call condition using `?` or when i add a null check when i add `!`.

I am trying to add a comment on an item from a list view in another screen and to do that i tried to retrieve the title of the item. Then when the user adds a comment, the comment will be added in the firestore with in a document that has the title of the item and the comment.

The problem is that i get that error in this line:

```
then((value) => value.data()["titre"])
```

I tried adding `!` or `?`, but it just didn't work the problem keeps occurring. There were people who said that I should transform me to `then((value) =\> value.data\["titre"\])`, but with no clue can someone help me solve it ?

```
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

 class add_comment extends StatefulWidget {
 final DocumentReference docRef;
 const add_comment({key, required this.docRef, required titre})
  : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<add_comment> createState() => _add_commentState();
 }

class _add_commentState extends State<add_comment> {
  TextEditingController commentController = TextEditingController();
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: TextFormField(
              controller: commentController,
              minLines: 1,
              maxLength: 5,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15))),
            )),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 25,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () async {
                  final Map<String, dynamic> commentData = {
                    'title': widget.docRef
                        .get()
                        .then((value) => value.data()["titre"]),
                    'text': commentController.text,
                  };
                  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('comments')
                      .doc(widget.docRef.id)
                      .collection('comments')
                      .add(commentData);
                  // Clear the comment text field
                  commentController.clear();
                  // Show a message to the user
                  // Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  //   SnackBar(content: Text('Comment added')
                  //   ),
                  //);
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The method '\[\]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575893/the-method-cant-be-unconditionally-invoked-because-the-receiver-can-be-nu)

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear: since your `value` is a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), its `value.data()` property is an `Object?`. The `?` here means that `data()` can return null, which your code needs to handle.

A good way to tell your code what to do when `value.data()` is null is to use the `?` coalescing and `??` operators:

```
value.data()?["titre"] ?? "no data found"
```

So here we say that, if `value.data()` is null, we'll return "no data found" instead.

---

There are more problems in your code though. Since you're calling `widget.docRef.get()`, that data is loaded from the database and is an asynchronous operation that returns a `Future`.  You're handling that Future with `then`, but your `.then((value) => ...)` code will never render the value.

I recommend first checking whether the code actually works, by printing the value from the database:

```
.then((value) => {
  print(value.data()?["titre"] ?? "no data found");
})
```

Or since it is now a block of code, we can use more readable constructs than `?` and `??` and get the same result with:

```
.then((doc) => {
  if (doc != null) {
    var value = doc!
    print(value["titre"]);
  } else {
    print("no data found");
  }
})
```